# How to change IP of ESP32 acting as an access point

Tags: arduino, ip, wifi, esp32

So my goal here is to set the IP of my ESP32. I'm using this piece of code to do so, but I always end up with "192.168.4.1" - I want it to be: 192, 168, 1, 1

```
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  IPAddress Ip(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress NMask(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(Ip, Ip, NMask);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.println(myIP);
```

Comment: try to stop it first with WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); or  with WiFi.softAPdisconnect()

Comment: Seems like you've solved it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stop the WiFi with WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

Answer (score 2):

To me it was happening that the IP was getting back to default 192.168.4.1 even if I was setting it. Basically you have to launch the AP before the configuration and wait a bit that the AP is set.

Refer to this post for more info [Wifi.softAPConfig() sometimes set the wrong IP address](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/985)

```
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); 
  WiFi.softAP(ssidAP, passwordAP);   //launch the access point
  Serial.println("Wait 100 ms for AP_START...");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Setting the AP");
  IPAddress Ip(192, 168, 123, 123);    //setto IP Access Point same as gateway
  IPAddress NMask(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(Ip, Ip, NMask);
```